# How to use ScadaLTS to transfer values from one device to another every minute?

Tags: scadalts

I am trying to use ScadaLTS to transfer an outside air temperature value from one device to another.

I used an entry in "point links", but when I save it, it executes the transfer one time and then it never does it again. I am sure I need to add something in the script section to tell it to keep doing this..

In the script window I have the following statement and nothing else:

return source.value;

I would like it to transfer every minute or so. Does anyone have any ideas on how-to do this? What scripting language is it looking for and what are the tags? Is it just looking for source.value and target.value?

I am very new to Scada-LTS, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What protocol do you use to download data and set up?